# Unable to implement Grails-jaxrs multipart file upload integration Test

Tags: grails, file-upload, jax-rs, integration-testing

I am using [grails-jaxrs](https://code.google.com/p/grails-jaxrs/)  for exposing an api which accepts multipart/form-data..

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(['application/json'])
    @Path('/addMessage')
    ChatMessage addChatMessageWithAttachment(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        log.debug "> addChatMessageWithAttachment"
        def fileStores = []
        def chatMessage
        GrailsWebRequest request = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
        def params = request.getParams()
        if (!(params.messageBody.length() > 0)) {
            log.error("Empty message body")
            throw new LocalisedException(ErrorCode.CHAT_MESSAGE_CREATE_FAILED)
        }
      }
```

The implementation is working properly as expected. I am able to send form-data (with file and other parameters successfully.

Now I am trying to implement integration test for above logic.

I am using IntegrationTestCase to achieve this.. so my code snippet is as below:

```
class ChatMessageResourceV1Tests extends IntegrationTestCase{
    //other implementation and setup ommited    

    @Test
    void "Create new chat message for event id - customer user"() {
        def headers = ['Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'application/json']

        def data = "My message..."
        def cm = new ChatMessage(messageBody: data)

        def content = "{'eventId':'$event.id','messageBody':'My message...'}"
        sendRequest("/api/v1/chatMessage/addMessage", 'POST', headers, content.bytes)

        assertEquals(200, response.status)
        }    

}
```

When I run the test.. I can see the call reaches inside the API method.. But however, the parameter messageBody is coming as null and exception is being thrown.

I have tried every possible combination of test.. But no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.